# Can database tables be resource entities in REST?

Tags: database, rest, service, resources, models

I want to create RESTful webservice that uses **database tables** as resource entities.

```
PUT myservice/table/new creates a new table in database
DELETE myservice/table/1 deletes a table in database and so on...
```

How do I design a model for this? usually the models are created for tables in which resource entities reside but my resources are not present in any table but the database itself!

Is that possible or am I not making any sense? Please help me!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: it is possible... BUT: what exactly have you tried ? what is your goal ? what is not working ?

Comment: My goal is to create a service that lets me create tables dynamically and each table is used as a resource in turn. Let me give an example Lets say i want to create a report data database. many clients push data into it and each has its own table. now if a new client comes up a new table has to be created on the fly and he can push data into that. did u get a gist of it? let me know if u need some more info. Thanks!

Comment: ok... and: what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: I am unable to come up with a web service design as i am confused if this is the right way to do or any other exists.

Comment: it is really hard to help... I just don't know what you want... the requirements of your project are the foundation to evaluate whether this is "the right way"... since I don't know anything about your project and your question is extremely vague I don't see a way to help...

Comment: It sounds very strange that you want to create a table for each client but if that is important in your solution, I don't see why not.

You need to provide a better question if you want answers. Is your question about how to design a RESTful interface or how to create/delete tables in a database? Either way, make a precise question or I believe this question will get deleted eventually. Others should benefit from reading the question and answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll keep it in mind from now on. My question was the design of restful interface for which I was confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, because REST relies on a very abstract and flexible concept of resources. As long as the interface obeys the uniform interface (standard methods, using URI's, etc) you can do *anything* you like behind the scenes. One of the best reasons to make an HTTP interface to something is to hide ugly implementation details and present just such a uniform interface.

Exactly how you do that in your language or environment of choice is a far more detailed question, but the basics would be something like this CherryPy pseudo-code:

```
class Table:
    exposed = True
    def __init__(self, tablename):
        self.tablename = tablename
    def PUT(self):
        fields = parse_fields(cherrypy.request.body.read())
        db.execute("CREATE TABLE %s (%s)" % (self.tablename, fields))
    def DELETE(self):
        db.execute("DROP TABLE %s" % self.tablename)

class Tables:
    def _cp_dispatch(self, vpath):
        return Table(vpath.pop(0))
```

You'll have to wire up the 'db' connection logic yourself, and figure out how much control the client should have over the field definitions (and what media type is best to communicate that, and how to parse that media type into valid SQL for the CREATE TABLE statement). You'll also want *much* better security than "DROP TABLE {user input}" ;) But hopefully this gets you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It cleared out most of the things.